# How to make an extension method on interface available on all implementing classes?

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I have a class *Triangle* and I added an extension method to the type *List<Triangle>* as shown below. It works just as one would expect.

```
public static string Export(this List<Triangle> self) { ... }
```

However, I also have other classes, like *Rectangle* and *Trapezoid*, which would need each own *Export* function, like this.

```
public static string Export(this List<Rectangle> self) { ... }
public static string Export(this List<Trapezoid> self) { ... }
```

Since the code in it the method is exactly the same and will remain so for any new kind of figure, I figured out (get it? *figured* out) that it's suitable to go for an interface. So, the classes are now implementing *IFigure*, which allowed me to consolidate the code in the extensions as shown below.

```
    public static string Export(this List<IFigure> self) { ... }
```

The only problem is that now the code doesn't compile because the lists of specific implementations doesn't know about the extension method. I'll have to change all the methods that return the type e.g. *List* to returning type *List<IFigure>* and it seems like a lot of work. Besides that, I fear that I then will need to convert those lists to the actual implmented classes for all the operations except the exporting.

Is it possible to have an extension method on interface type so that it covers all the implementing classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use generics to make it resolve:

```
public static string Export<TFigure>(this List<TFigure> self)
    where TFigure : IFigure
{ ... }
```

Inside the method you will have all of the properties/methods of IFigure on the elements inside the self list.

It'll work for a list of IFigure itself or any inherited types

```
new List<IFigure>().Export();
new List<Triangle>().Export();
```

The TFigure is just the name of the generic declaration (it could be anything or just T to keep it simple). The **where TFigure : IFigure** will tell the compiler that it should only accept a type that implements IFigure. This is called a generic constraint.

Answer (score 4):

An extension method on IEnumerable<> will work

```
public static string Export(this IEnumerable<IFigure> self) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, because of the covariance of `IEnumerable<out T>`. For the same reason, you can put the extension method on `IReadOnlyList<out T>` if the method uses list stuff (such as index access).

Comment: That would require me to change the type of the object I'm working with (it's a *List<Type>*, not *IEnumerable<Type>*). I could, of course, convert it back and fort but it seems to me an ineffective solution.

Comment: You don't have change the type. The extension method will be accessible on a List<Type> because it implements IEnumerable<Type>.